# Dynamic Table in LINQ to SQL query

Tags: c#, linq

I have several references in DB with same table structure.
I don't want to write several LINQ queries to each db. Is it possible to develop one query with dynamic Table parameter?
My query example:

```
var query =
            from myTranslations in myContext.translations
            where myTranslations.code == strLabelCode
            select myTranslations;
```

Comment: If you've duplicated the same structure multiple times in your database... you've probably got a basic design problem. Why not refactor al those "Same Table Structures" into a single table structure & differentiate between the data they contain using a TypeId.

Comment: I can't do that because one reference can be for details and other for   users. It's not good experience to sore them together.

Answer (score 1):

No, sorry. Simple like that - only via for example reflection, which makes it - ah - hard er than having multiple table objects.

Answer (score 0):

Use datacontext GetTable() method to vary table type as listed here [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb357220.aspx)